# Why Model.find is not storing data in variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to create and save new model instances and assign a unique id to each of them in my MONGODB Atlas database. To do this Im trying to get data from my models using Model.find() and store it in a variable where I can loop through the array and check if id assigned already exists in the collection objects. I can succesfully log the collection but it seems that I cant store the colletion array in a variable.

Whenever I try to console.log(dbData) I get undefined,  should I also have to call model.find in a get request that points to the form action path whenever a form is submited?

```
 var formModel=mongoose.model("Form-Model", newFormSchema)


    let dbData =formModel.find({}, function(err,data){
        if(err) console.error(err)
        console.log(data)
        return data
    })

        let rndm=2
        function isUnique(rndm){
          let unique=dbData.some(element=>element.id===rndm)
          while(unique){
            rndm=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)
            unique=arr.some(element=>element.id===rndm)
          }

         return rndm
        }


    app.post("/form-data",function(req,res){

        console.log(req.body)
        var newForm= new formModel({
            output:req.body.output,
            id:isUnique(rndm)
        })
        newForm.save()
        res.send("new user submited")
        res.end()
    })
```

EDIT//////

I saw somewhere else that you need either a promise or async/await to wait for model.find to finish getting objects array but when console.logging(dbData) I get promise pending ,

```
async function dbData() {
try{
let dbData= await formModel.find({})
return dbData
    }
catch(err){
console.log(err)
    }

}
console.log(dbData()) // returns Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: Callbacks doesn't work that way, whatever you get from DB will be in `data` of `function(err,data)` what are you trying to do with `dbData` ?

Comment: I want db data to return an array by calling Model.find(), but it returns a pending promise instead @whoami

Comment: You have to `await dbData()` because the *function* `dbData()` returns a `Promise`, just like you `await formModel.find()` because it returns a `Promise`

Comment: Would I have to embed it into another async function? how could I use await? tried using it in console.log(await dbData()), but it gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

use .then(function(res)
//execude code with returned result from async function here
)